# Is there a way to change front output to rear output?

Tags: audio

The front audio output panel of my desktop computer is broken. The green hole. Though others(rear, side, center and woofer) work just fine, so I wonder if there's a way to change or swap front output to one of those.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options you can try:

- Find your computer case manufacturer and purchase a new audio panel.  Generally, manufacturers have plenty of these in spare parts.  They might even send it to you for free if the computer is old enough and they want to get rid of inventory.  You would simply disconnect the cables and pop the old panel out, then attach the new one.  Depending on the panel, it might be generic enough to use a different manufacturers audio panel.
- You can try to repair the broken jack.  If you are good with a soldering iron, you can try to replace the jack.  Here is one example of a replacement [jack](http://www.showmecables.com/product/3-5mm-Stereo-Jack-Open-Panel-Connector-Plastic.aspx?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cse&utm_campaign=891&gclid=CjwKEAjw7qi7BRCvsr3N58GvsTkSJAA3UzLvRMzW_XXrGW-ynxtL9zqYRHRQNYBQWs5RdDOSTDpHcxoCZ_Dw_wcB).  Mechanically and electronically, they are all the same, so as long as it will fit where you need it, it will work.
- Worst case, you can you can splice in a long extension and route it as needed.  Purchase one of [these](http://www.walmart.com/ip/24358884?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0&adid=22222222227017782185&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=40882289432&wl4=&wl5=pla&wl6=78811915232&veh=sem) and cut off the male end and strip the ends of the wires.  Cut the wires going to the broken jack and strip the ends.  Connect the wires that went to the jack to the extension and you are good to go.
- Another option would be to buy a cheap sound card and use that instead
- The last option, which is rare, is that some audio device drivers let you change the type of connection the jack is.  This is usually only found on higher end audio cards though and would most likely not be found on an onboard sound card.

Answer (score 0):

The panel may be connected to your sound card (or the motherboard, if integrated sound) by an analog audio cable. I have seen a solution like this where the cable head consisted of several separate 1-pin sockets that one could freely rearrange to match any pin layout. In this case it is easy to remap channels.

Example:

[image: 6CH audio interface]

(The picture source [here](http://www.fixya.com/support/t1564222-asus_p5gd1_vm_front_definition_audio_pin).)